# Overwriting a nested array into the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
var state2 = {
    editValue0: "Australia123",
    editValue1: "Europe123",
    editValue2: "Asia123",
    editValue3: "Africa123",
    selectedQuestion: [
         {
            id: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    opt: "Australia"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Europe"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Asia"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Africa"
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

I want the value of `opt` to bereplaced by the corresponsidng index value of editValue, eg., options[0].opt is `Australia`, so it should replace the value of editvalue0 , and so on. I tried the following, but error is coming:

```
state2.selectedQuestion[0].options.map(function(e,i){
Object.assign(state2.editValue0,e.opt)
})
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the key dynamically based on index and if the value corresponding to the key exist, you need to replace the value. This you can achieve without mutating the state using `spread syntax` and `Array.prototype.map`

```js
var state = {
    editValue0: "Australia123",
    editValue1: "Europe123",
    editValue2: "Asia123",
    editValue3: "Africa123",
    selectedQuestion: [
         {
            id: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    opt: "Australia"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Europe"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Asia"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Africa"
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}

const newState = {
    ...state,
    selectedQuestion: state.selectedQuestion.map((data) => {
        return {
            ...data,
            options: data.options.map((opt, i) => {
               const key = `editValue${i}`;
               return {
                opt: state[key]? state[key]: opt.opt
               }
            })
        }
    })
}
console.log(newState);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need map here as you are not changing array here.
You can use forEach loop through options and you need to override dynamic key to state2 using `state2["editValue" + index]` or

```
state2[`editValue${index}`
```

```js
var state2 = {
    editValue0: "Australia123",
    editValue1: "Europe123",
    editValue2: "Asia123",
    editValue3: "Africa123",
    selectedQuestion: [
         {
            id: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    opt: "Australia"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Europe"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Asia"
                },
                {
                    opt: "Africa"
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}

state2.selectedQuestion[0].options.forEach((obj, index) => {
Object.assign(state2, { [`editValue${index}`]: obj.opt })
})

console.log(state2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a forEach loop

```js
var state2 = {
  editValue0: "Australia123",
  editValue1: "Europe123",
  editValue2: "Asia123",
  editValue3: "Africa123",
  selectedQuestion: [{
    id: 1,
    options: [{
        opt: "Australia"
      },
      {
        opt: "Europe"
      },
      {
        opt: "Asia"
      },
      {
        opt: "Africa"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
state2.selectedQuestion.forEach(function(e){e.options.forEach(function(k,l){
state2["editValue"+l]=k.opt;
})})
console.log(state2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `forEach` along with the index to assign values:

```js
var state2 = {
  editValue0: "Australia123",
  editValue1: "Europe123",
  editValue2: "Asia123",
  editValue3: "Africa123",
  selectedQuestion: [{
    id: 1,
    options: [{
        opt: "Australia"
      },
      {
        opt: "Europe"
      },
      {
        opt: "Asia"
      },
      {
        opt: "Africa"
      }
    ]

  }]
};

state2.selectedQuestion[0].options.forEach((e, i) => {state2['editValue' + i] = e.opt;});
console.log(state2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate loop on options and then replace the corresponding value against key.

```
var state2 = {
      editValue0: "Australia123",
      editValue1: "Europe123",
      editValue2: "Asia123",
      editValue3: "Africa123",
      selectedQuestion: [{
        id: 1,
        options: [{
            opt: "Australia"
          },
          {
            opt: "Europe"
          },
          {
            opt: "Asia"
          },
          {
            opt: "Africa"
          }
        ]

      }]
    };
    for(let i = 0; i < state2.selectedQuestion.length; i++) {
        let optionList = state2.selectedQuestion[i]['options'];
        for(let j = 0; j < optionList.length; j++) {
            let option = optionList[j];
            state2["editValue" + j] = option["opt"];
        }
    }
    console.log(state2);
```